# FLutter: Error connecting to the service protocol

Tags: android, ios, windows, flutter, dart

Flutter shows the error: 'Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to' Https. How to rectify this?

Comment: Can you provide the full console output? There's really not much to go on here.

Comment: @BenKonyi I solved the issue, but if you still want the console output i was getting earlier i can put it in

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I've tried turning off Wifi on my laptop and iPhones, disabled "connect via network" in XCode, restarted all the phones and my laptop...

Comment: @Agam can you say how you actually solved the issue?

Comment: @Agam can you please explain how you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, using an android emulator with API 28(Android 9)...